# How to show data in a hbs template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, handlebars.js, nestjs

Need some help with this, I'm trying to show data in the template but it doesn't works. I'm using NestJS with mysql.

Here the code of the controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Put, Delete, Body, Param, Render, UsePipes, Logger, UseGuards} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductoService } from './producto.service';
import { ProductoDTO } from './producto.dto';
import { ValidationPipe } from '../shared/validation.pipe';


@Controller('producto')
export class ProductoController {
    private logger = new Logger('ProductoController');

    constructor(private productoService: ProductoService){}

    @Get('index')
    //@UseGuards(new AuthGuard())
    @Render('Producto/index')
    showAllUsers(){
        return {product:this.productoService.showAll().then(function(result){
            var aux = [{}];
            aux = result;
            console.log(aux);
            return aux;

        })};        
    }
}
```

Here the code of the index.hbs handlebars template:

```
<h2>Lista de Productos</h2>
<div class="entry">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>           
            {{#each aux}}
                <td>{{this.name}}</td>
                <td>{{this.quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{this.description}}</td>
            {{/each}} 
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
</div>
```

even in the console log show me the data.

[image: image data log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think nestjs will automatically wait for nested promises to resolve. So it will return `{product: Promise}`.

I would advise to make your method `async`:

```
@Get('index')
async showAllUsers(){
    const products = await this.productoService.showAll();
    return {products};        
}
```

Also, in your hbs template you're referring to `aux` although you return `{product: [...]}`. So it should be `{{#each product}}` instead. (I have renamed it to `products` in the example above because it's an array.)

Comment: Thank you, it works! I'm beginning with this framework.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you now. Welcome to Stackoverflow. :-)